Re-exporting antd components while keeping /es direcory available
I am using yarn workspaces for my project, with following structure
root
   packages
      app1
          tsconfig.json
      app2
      ui-kit
          ant-design
              index.d.ts
          tsconfig.json
   tsconfig.json

in index.d.ts I am re-exporting antd component wrapped with additional props, but antd has a lot of types in antd/es/* I need to use in my project.
I dont want to re-export all of them (because there is a lot of them and structure might change).
So I modified ui-kit/tsconfig.json to be
{
    "extends": "@my-config-lib/tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "ant-design/es/*": ["node_modules/antd/es/*"]
        },
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.d.ts"],
    "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}

While this help me to import from within ui-ki using ./ant-design/es/menu/etc
This does not work when this ui-kit is used in app1 or app2.
I tried setting references in app1/tsconfig.json but that does not seem to help.
Also i have tried adding paths in app1/tsconfig.json to be "@fineapp/ui-kit/antd-design/es*" : "../ui-kit/node_modules/antd/es/*"
but also no luck.
Is there a way to tell app1/tsconfig to look for paths in ui-kit/tsconfig.json while trying import code from it ?
